# Rule extraction of financial time series in R

Tags: r, algorithm, data-mining

I struggle with a rule extraction algorithm using R. Generally, I had a financial time series, which I splited into different segments according to the trend and duration. As I result I got a data frame similar to this below:

```
 > head(DF)
  Segment   trend  duration description  
1       1       C         S         C_S 
2       2      VP         L        VP_L  
3       3      VN         S        VN_S 
4       4       N         S         N_S  
5       5       P         M         P_M  
6       6      VP         M        VP_M
```

where VN,N,C,P,VP (very negative, negative, constant, positive, very positive) describe the trend that occured during selected segment, S,M,L (short, medium, long) describe the duration of each segment and the last column is just a combination of the previous.
All I want to obtain are rules, where LHS contains historic information about segments and RHS is the future segment.
So for example one rule could look like this:

```
 ID   Rule                                  Support Confidence 
 R5   seg(t-2): VP_B & seg(t-1): N_S             10      71.4%
        => seg(t): P_M
```

I want to emphasize that the segments used to create the rule should be sequential. Any ideas about proposed algorithm or r package would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this looks like a full project more than a specific question.

Comment: yes, indeed it is. but all I need is a little advice from person who is familiar with this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the arules package:

```
Lines <- "Segment   trend  duration description  
1       1       C         S         C_S 
2       2      VP         L        VP_L  
3       3      VN         S        VN_S 
4       4       N         S         N_S  
5       5       P         M         P_M  
6       6      VP         M        VP_M"


library(arules)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, FUN = identity)
lags <- as.data.frame(lag(z$description, 0:-2))

a <- apriori(lags)
inspect(a)
```

See the `vignette("arules")` for more information.

Another thing to try is:

```
library(rpart)
rpart(lag0 ~., lags)
```

Comment: This sounds like what I am looking for, but i got this error: 
Error in as(data, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “formula” to “transactions”

Comment: This works almost perfectly but segments are not consequent, e.g.
 {lag0=VN_L,  lag-2=N_S}  => {lag-1=N_S} . I tried to set  appearance = list(rhs="lag0") in apriori function but it returns me an error.

Comment: Take the subset of rules where the rhs involves lag0.

Comment: It's fine now. Thanks!